# Using Perl to preprocess C file

Tags: regex, perl

**This is my input C file**

```
/**
********************************************************************************
 *  @fn ChainCtrlSetJpgSnapshotFile                                             
 *  @brief
 *  @param[in ]                                                                   
 *  @return
********************************************************************************
*/
eErrorT ChainCtrlSetJpgSnapshotFile(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, RouteListItemT* pRoute, char * dst_chain, char *jpg_file_path)
{
    ...
}

/**
********************************************************************************
 *  @fn ChainCtrlSetBgFile                                                      
 *  @brief
 *  @param[in ]                                                                   
 *  @return
********************************************************************************
*/
eErrorT ChainCtrlSetBgFile(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, RouteListItemT* pRoute, char * dst_chain, char *bg_file_path)
{ 
   ...
}
```

**My Perl code**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw(@temp $index);

open(my $FILE, "< a.c") or die $!;  ;

my @arr = <$FILE>;
my $pos = 0;

foreach(@arr){
$pos++; 
if ($_ =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg) {
  my $arg = $1;
  $index = $pos;
  my @arr = map /(\w+)$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;
  @temp = map ' *  @param[in/out] '."$_\n", @arr;
 }
}

$arr[$index - 5] = "";
splice @arr,$index-4,0,@temp;
print @arr;

close($FILE);
```

**the erroneous output I am getting**

```
/**
********************************************************************************
 *  @fn ChainCtrlSetJpgSnapshotFile                                             
 *  @brief
 *  @param[in ]                                                                   
 *  @return
********************************************************************************
*/
eErrorT ChainCtrlSetJpgSnapshotFile(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, RouteListItemT* pRoute, char * dst_chain, char *jpg_file_path)
{
    ...
}

/**
********************************************************************************
 *  @fn ChainCtrlSetBgFile                                                      
 *  @brief
 *  @param[in/out] pChainCtrl
 *  @param[in/out] pRoute
 *  @param[in/out] dst_chain
 *  @param[in/out] bg_file_path
 *  @return
********************************************************************************
*/
eErrorT ChainCtrlSetBgFile(ChainCtrlT* pChainCtrl, RouteListItemT* pRoute, char * dst_chain, char *bg_file_path)
{ ....

}
```

I am trying to add the names of each function's arguments into the comment section just above it.

My code works only for the last function definition, but I need it to work for all of the functions in the C file.

I guess I am making a mistake with `splice`, but using `splice` inside the `foreach` loop makes it run indefinitely with no output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent half an hour to see your program and below is the right answer.It seems it is just because of  a simple logic error.So ,if you like please give some scores to  me.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw(@temp $index);

open(my $FILE, "< a.c") or die $!;  ;

my @arr = <$FILE>;
my $pos = 0;

foreach(@arr){
$pos++; 
if ($_ =~ /^ \S+ \s+ \S+ \s* \( (.+?) \) /xsmg) {
  my $arg = $1;
  $index = $pos;
  my @arr = map /(\w+)$/, split /\W*?,\W*/, $arg;
  @temp = map ' *  @param[in/out] '."$_\n", @arr;
  $arr[$index - 5] = "";
  splice @arr,$index-4,0,@temp;
 }
}

print @arr;
close($FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The three lines containing the `splice` are written outside the for loop and the if. Hence they are only executed once, just before the file is closed.

Move the two closing curly braces of the `for` loop and the `if` to just before the `close` statement.

The loop runs on and on with the splice inside the because it adds more lines into the array each time around the loop.

An underlying problem with the way the code is written is that the array `@arr` is being processed by the `foreach (@arr)` loop and extra elements are being spliced into the array within the loop. Perl is good at doing the "right thing" when code like that is written. Your code keeps indexes into the array (ie `$pos` and `$index`) by counting. Those counts are not being adjusted when elements are spliced into the array before the elements the indexes refer to.

Comment: and if i write it inside it goes into infinite loop

Comment: @Ad-vic My mistake with my first answer.

Comment: $arr[$index - 5] = "";
splice @arr,$index-4,0,@temp; should be inside both of bracket

Comment: and print should be outside bracket. But still problem with splice. $index-4 for first function is fine. But for second function its 4 lines above the template.

Comment: @Ad-vic The splice is adding four lines into the array but `$pos` is not being adjusted to match those added lines.

Comment: I got that..i fixed it using increment operator..thanks for the tips